# Control-C exception upon release the target process

Tags: windbg

I'm using Ntsd.exe to explore .NET advanced debugging. I have success breaking into the process but upon process resumption (g). I get the below exception. I don't recall this happening previously. Is this normal?

(f38.2f0): Control-C exception - code 40010005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this question by setting the control-c exception to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two choices:

`gh` to continue by setting the exception to be already handled

or

`sxd cce` or `sxn cce` to turn of handling those exceptions (without or with notification) in general